# Aggregating polygons with Basic level licence of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, aggregation, basic-license-level

I need to aggregate near-by polygons, but it has to work with a Basic ArcGIS Desktop Licence. I can't use the Aggregate tool (only Advanced) and I can't use the buffer tool, because the rounded edges create a lot of unnecessary points (flat edges are not available with a Basic License).

The accuracy is not very important (the less points created the better), it should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work with basic license:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("ORIGINAL", "/single_buffer.shp", .. dissolve_option="ALL")
arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management(in_features="single_buffer","..many_buffers.shp")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("many_buffers", "Id", "[FID]+1")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("ORIGINAL", "many_buffers")
arcpy.Dissolve_management("sj", "../RESULT.shp", dissolve_field="Id")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("RESULT", field="Shape", expression="!Shape!.convexHull()", expression_type="PYTHON_9.3", code_block="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for (the last Calculate Field step)! Does this only work with shapefiles and not fc?

Comment: If you work with database, start editing session.

Comment: Editing session let's ArcGis recalculate area and perimeter.

Answer (score 2):

You can buffer with dissolve type all then run [Integrate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) to reduce the number of vertices:

> Integrate is used to maintain the integrity of shared feature
>   boundaries by making features coincident if they fall within the
>   specified x,y tolerance. Features that fall within the specified x,y
>   tolerance are considered identical or coincident.

Integrate should give you results comparable to [Simplify Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/simplify-polygon.htm) (which requires higher license level).